# How to remove new line after </ul> tag

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to force new line after the `</ul>` tag. There is one `<ul>` with second `<ul>` inside. But can't make it work..

There is a code, I hope you will understand what I want to have. I just want to have the `<ul>` with social networks on the same line as the rest of the menu. Thank you for all advices!

HTML:

```
<ul id="m1">
<ul id="m2">
    <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="/gallery">GALERIE</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact">KONTAKT</a></li>
</ul>

<li style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><a class="fb" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"></a></li>

<li style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><a class="bz" href=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#m1 li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 18px;
padding-left: 18px;
font-size: 18px;
}

#m2 li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 18px;
padding-left: 18px;
font-size: 18px;
}

#m1 {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}

#m2 {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is not correct, Add second ul after the first.

```css
#m1 li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 18px;
padding-left: 18px;
font-size: 18px;
}

#m2 li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 18px;
padding-left: 18px;
font-size: 18px;
}

#m1 {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}

#m2 {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul id="m2">
    <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="/gallery">GALERIE</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact">KONTAKT</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="m1">

<li style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><a class="fb" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>

<li style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><a class="bz" href="">Other</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, I want to have nav menu on the left side and social network's banners on the right side

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you want?

```
<ul id="m1">
<li>
// HERE YOU HAVE A LIST INSIDE ANOTHER LIST
    <ul id="m2">
         <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
         <li><a href="/gallery">GALERIE</a></li>
         <li><a href="/contact">KONTAKT</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>    
<li style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">
     <a class="fb" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"></a>
</li>    
<li style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">
     <a class="bz" href=""></a>
</li>
</ul>
```